# Why does my sidebar not turn rounded even though I added border radius?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to this site and I hope I'm doing okay.

anyway, im having a problem where i can't make the  border of my sidebar rounded. weird cuz I already did it with an earlier project with `border-radius`.

here's the code

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr ;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(150px, auto);
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "one one one "
    "two three four"
    "two three four"
}


.grid-item-1 {
    grid-area: one;
}

.grid-item-2 {
    grid-area: two;
}

.grid-item-3 {
    grid-area: three;
}

.grid-item-4 {
    grid-area: four;

}

.wrapper > div {
    background: #90334c;
    padding: 1em;
}

.wrapper > div:nth-child(odd){
    background: #ee9849;
}
.sidenav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100vh;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: auto; 
    font-size: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    
   
}

.sidenav a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 120%;
    color: #ddd;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 16px 18px;
    background-color: #8b7484;
    text-decoration: none;

}

.sidenav a:hover {
    background-color:lightgray;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

if you wanna access the entire code here https://codepen.io/rujin7/pen/yLjJQdb as i am also having a problem inserting icons beside the navigation list

Comment: Are you talking about `.sidenav` ? You could try `.sidenav > ul { border-radius: 10px; overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: Well it is, kind of. Add `background-color: blue;` to sidenav and you can see where you have the rounded border. I'm not sure but I guess it is in `<div class="grid-item grid-item-2">` you want the rounding.

Comment: Where do you actually want the rounding? Is it on the mushroomy-colored item (that's all the lis) or do you want the bit round the text Menu included or....

Comment: `.sidenav` _has_ rounded borders. But as it has no background color, they don't show.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to add a background color to the element you want rounded corners in order for it to be visible.

And the element you are looking for is `.sidenav > ul`:

```css
.sidenav > ul {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #8b7484;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Then remove the background from your navigation links:

```css
.sidenav a {
  background-color: #8b7484; // remove this!
}
```